# Facebook - meta tag might be a wrong?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I just checked my site is not working in facebook.
I have added facebook meta tags for title, description, thumbnail image.

I checked my site and found it is working and i can share links in windows 7

But i checked today in windows 8 and linux. (ubuntu and fedora)
They are not working and i am not able to share links.

I checked the debug link which is also working and scrapping the link details in windows 7. But it is not working in linux and windows 8.

What could be the problem in my site?
I suspect meta tags.

meta tags are inclued in head tag.
That was my doctype and html tag

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $fb_title; ?>"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $fb_url;?>"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="images/<?php echo $fb_images;?>"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php echo $fb_page_name;?>"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="my_id"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $fb_description;?>"/>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Comment: why are ur meta tags outside the scope of the html?

Comment: no, meta tags are inside the head tag. I just mentioned my doctype and html tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the result by using this [facebook link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).

If you don't know it yet, you're using [Open Graph Protocol](http://opengraphprotocol.org/).

You have to put `meta` inside `<head />` part.

For my part, I use this DOM when i wan't to add Facebook button :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" >
<head>
<title>My site</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="author" content="JoDev, France" />
<meta name="keywords" content="some, word, that, can, resume, the, site" />
<meta property="og:title" content="My site title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://url.to/your/site" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://url.to/your/preview/image" />
<meta property="og:site-name" content="My Site name" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Using this, you will be able to reach for the moon" />
```